# Optimize slow powershell script

Tags: powershell, optimization, powershell-3.0

I wrote this script  and it  works   but its painfully  slow,  can you please  point out  why ?   and provide some  ideas on how to optimize its  functionality.   in  can make  simple  Powershell scrips however I have a very had  time  looking up  methodology on google  not knowing  what to look for

**my script**

```
$i=1;
foreach ($PC in $ComputerName) {
    $per = ($i/$ComputerName.Length)*100

    try {
        
        # Get-ADComputer $pcs -properties  name,enabled | select-object name,enabled

        $status = Get-ADComputer -Identity $PC -Properties Enabled | select-object -ExpandProperty Enabled
        
        if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $PC -Quiet -Count 1){
            $quserOut = quser.exe /SERVER:$PC 2>&1

            if ($quserOut -match "No user exists"){ 
                "$PC>On Line>$status>No users loggedIn"; continue 
            
            }else{
            
                $users = $quserOut -replace '\s{2,}', ',' |
                ConvertFrom-CSV -Header 'username', 'sessionname', 'id', 'state', 'idleTime', 'logonTime' |
                Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerName -Value $PC -PassThru
            
                $users = $users[1..$users.count]
            
                for ($i = 0; $i -lt $users.count; $i++){
                    if ($users[$i].sessionname -match '^\d+$'){
                        $users[$i].logonTime = $users[$i].idleTime
                        $users[$i].idleTime = $users[$i].STATE
                        $users[$i].STATE = $users[$i].ID
                        $users[$i].ID = $users[$i].SESSIONNAME
                        $users[$i].SESSIONNAME = $null
                    }
                }
                $users = $users | Sort-Object -Property idleTime
                
                # $status = Get-ADComputer -Identity $PC -Properties Enabled | select-object -ExpandProperty Enabled
                $Usr = $users | Where-Object { $_.state -eq 'Active' } | select-object -ExpandProperty username
                "$PC>On Line>$status>$Usr"
            }

        } else {
            "$PC>Not Online>$status>NoUserDataRetrieve"
        }

    }
    catch {
        "$PC>Not in AD>$status>NoUserDataRetrieve"
    }


    Write-Progress -Activity "Procesando  Usuarios:" -Status "Usuario EN Proceso: $i -- $PC" -PercentComplete $per
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100

    $i++
}
```

**this displays  the  following data**

basically  script  test  if PC exist in Active Directory,  it does a ping test , and gets  back  current logged in user

```
    Machine Name  > Ping Test pass? >  AD status  > current logged in user 


    PC1>Online>True>BazVic
    PC2>NotOnLine>True>No Available Data
    PC3>OnLine>True>ReyesDa
    PC2>NotOnLine>FALSE>No Available Data
```

Comment: [1] normally, one posts optimize requests in >>> Code Review Stack Exchange — https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ <<< [*grin*] ///// [2] you seem to be going thru the `$Users` collection many times. try reducing that to just once if you can. ///// [3] the `Write-Progress` cmdlet is _notorious_ for slowing things down. it's the very 1st thing one is recommended to remove when trying to speed up powershell. ///// [4] the `Add-Member` cmdlet is also dead slow. try building your custom object with something like `[PSCustomObject]`.

Comment: `Test-Connection` will be slowing this down a lot. Use a `Try...Catch` structure and query the computer regardless, using the error trap to deal with unresponsive machines

Comment: Use `Measure-Command` to find out which parts are consuming most of the time.

Comment: The use of external commands (`quser.exe`) is also a bad (performance) practice (use cmdlets or .net instead). Besides you might consider to query the remote pcs in parallel.

Comment: There are several [performance profiling](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/powershell-profiling/) tools available on the internet.

Comment: Install PowerShell 7.x and use `foreach -Parallel` instead.